# Cognitive Searchの検索結果の一致箇所について

Tags: azure

Cognitive Searchにクエリを投げると、結果としてフィールド一覧が得られますが、
どのフィールドにクエリが一致したかを調べる方法はありますか。
方法があれば教えていただけないでしょうか。

いくつかのカスタムフィールドを作成し、それぞれに文章を格納しています。
これらのフィールドでクエリ検索を行い、一致したフィールドから文章を抽出したいです。
そのため、クエリが一致したフィールドの名称を特定する方法を教えてください。